# Is it possible to attach UIGestureRecognizer to subclassed UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

Getting a crash with "unrecognized selector sent to instance" message, when attaching a UIPanGestureRecognizer to subclassed UIImageView. I need to subclass UIImageView to hold custom properties, so I just did that and added those properties. I have tested panning on UIImageView directly, and it works as expected. However, it doesn't work with subclassed UIImageView. Here's the code (self.myImageView is subclassed UIImageView and self.defaultImageView is UIImageView ):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIPanGestureRecognizer * pgr = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveCustomImageView:)];
  [self.myImageView addGestureRecognizer:pgr]; //nop, getting error during runtime on start panning
  [pgr release];
  ...
  pgr = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveUIImageView:)];
  [self.defaultImageView addGestureRecognizer:pgr]; //yep, that works
  [pgr release];
```

The handler methods declarations are of the same structure

```
-(void)moveUIImageView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan{
  ...
}

-(void)moveCustomImageView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan{
  ...
}
```

Comment: The error message "unrecognized selector sent to instance" will tell you what the selector was that was unrecognized and the class of the instance you tried to send it to. That information should be added to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry but it appears that it was a typing error in handler method declaration (mistyped name) Also, after applying @Srikar suggestions everything worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIImageView` by default has `setUserInteractionEnabled` flag set to `NO` & `setMultipleTouchEnabled` set to `NO`. Did you try turning these flags to `YES`?

You can change this like so -

```
[self.myImageView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
[self.myImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```